# How to construct query using the SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have 3 models that look like this (simplified):

User:

```
id
username
```

Resource:

```
id
name
description
```

Comment:

```
id
user_id (relationship User)
resource_id (relationship Resource)
data
date_created
```

I am trying to query the comments for a user and group them by Resource. I'd like the results to come back as:
[(Resource A, [Comment, Comment, Comment, ...]), (Resource B, [Comment, Comment, ...]), (Resource X, [Comment])]

I have tried various ways of constructing this and I just can't seem to figure it out. What would be the proper way to do something like this?

EDIT

Right now the code looks like this:

```
contrib = db_session.query(Resource).filter(Comment.user==user, Resource.uuid==Comment.resource_id).distinct(Comment.resource_id).order_by(desc(Comment.date_created))
comments = db_session.query(Comment, Resource).filter(Comment.user==user, Comment.resource_id.in_([r.uuid for r in contrib]), Resource.uuid==Comment.resource_id).order_by(desc(Comment.date_created))
```

I then use some list/dictionary comprehension to combine these results into something that looks like

```
[{resource: Resource, comments:[Comment, Comment, Comment]}, {resource: Resource, comments:[Comment, .....]}, .....]
```

There has got to be a better way to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom [`MappedCollection`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/ru/latest/orm/collections.html#sqlalchemy.orm.collections.MappedCollection) to group the comments:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.collections import collection, MappedCollection

class GroupedCollection(MappedCollection):

  def __init__(self):
    super(GroupedCollection, self).__init__(
      self,
      lambda e: e.resource_id # the key we want to group by
    )

  @collection.internally_instrumented
  def __setitem__(self, key, value, _sa_initiator=None):
    if key in self:
      # there is already another comment for that resource
      # we simply append the comment (or you could do something
      # more fancy here if you would like to order the comments)
      self[key]['comments'].append(value)
    else:
      # we create a new entry with a dictionary containing the
      # resource and comment
      super(GroupedCollection, self).__setitem__(
        key,
        {'resource': value.resource, 'comments': [value]},
        _sa_initiator
      )
```

You then add the corresponding relationship on your `User` class:

```
class User(Base):

  # ...

  grouped_comments = relationship(
    'Comment',
    collection_class=GroupedCollection
  )
```

Accessing it will give you the comments grouped by resource:

```
>>> user.grouped_comments
{
  'resource_id_1': {'resource': <Resource 1>, 'comments': [<Comment ...>, <Comment ...>]},
  'resource_id_2': {'resource': <Resource 2>, 'comments': [<Comment ...>]}
}
>>> user.grouped_comments.values()
[
  {'resource': <Resource 1>, 'comments': [<Comment ...>, <Comment ...>]},
  {'resource': <Resource 2>, 'comments': [<Comment ...>]}
]
```

Note that this relationship should only be used to view the related models, enabling adding/deleting models would require extra work.

Finally, if this is a pattern you would like to reproduce, you can easily create a `GroupedCollection` factory function where you can specify the grouping key.

Comment: Wow - this is incredible and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. I have a question: if I were to slice this, so .values()[5:10], would it actually be returning all the results under the hood and then slicing the resulting python list, or would the slice apply to the query that SQLAlchemy was issuing? Is there anyway to affect the ordering or filtering of the comments being used to populate this structure? Maybe something like .grouped_comments.filter(Comment.startswith('the')).order_by(desc(Comment.date_created)) -> would that apply?

Thanks again!

Comment: Slicing `u.grouped_comments.values()` will slice the list and not the query. On the plus side though, the query will only run once - say you call `u.grouped_comments.values()[1:3]` and then `u.grouped_comments.values()[4:6]`, the query is only emitted once (as all the comments have been loaded the first time). You have a few options for ordering your results, you can either specify an [`order_by`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship) in the relationship or change the way they are appended in the `GroupedCollection` class.

Comment: If you often have to filter your results, I would recommend using a dynamic relationship instead (setting `lazy='dynamic'`) and implementing a separate grouping logic.

Answer (score 0):

Please check demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f2ea/2

Hope this helps

Comment: I didn't downvote you, just so you know, but this was really helpful for understanding how to setup the query. Not exactly what I am looking for (trying to return SQLAlchemy ORM objects), but much appreciated